# Упорядочить односвязный список. delphi

Tags: delphi, list, указатели

Необходимо упорядочить список: в начало положительные, затем 0, в конец отрицательные, при этом их порядок их следования не должен меняться, т.е. дан список `5, 0, 3, -9, 0, -8, 7` после его упорядочивания должно получиться так `5, 3, 7, 0, 0, -9, -8`

Сам код:

```
type
  TInfo = integer;
 
  PElem = ^TElem;
  TElem = record
      info: TInfo;
      next: PElem;
  end;

procedure AddR(var ListN, ListK: PElem; r: integer); // адреса начала и конца списка и R
var ListC: PElem;  // текущий элемент списка
begin
   if ListN = nil then CreateList(ListN , ListK, r) // если список пуст
     else
       if r > 0 then AddFirst(ListN, ListK, r) // добавить в начало
        else
         if r < 0 then AddLast(ListN, ListK, r) // добавить в конец
           else
             begin // найти после какого
               ListC:=ListN; // с начала списка
               while (ListC^.next <> nil) and (ListC^.next^.info > 0) do
               ListC := ListC^.next;
              AddMedium(ListN, ListC, ListK, r); // добавить после текущего
             end;
```

Процедуры добавления в начало/конец/середину списка:

```
procedure AddFirst(var ListN: PElem; ListK: PElem; r: TInfo);
    var Elem: PElem;
    begin
      new(Elem);
      Elem^.info:=r;
      Elem^.next:=ListN;
      ListN:=Elem; // теперь он 1-ый
    end;
     
    // добавить новый элемент в конец
    procedure AddLast(ListN: PElem; var ListK: PElem; r: TInfo);
    begin
      new(ListK^.next);
      ListK^.next^.info:=r;
      ListK^.next^.next:=nil;
      ListK:= ListK^.next;
    end;
     
    // добавить новый элемент в середину после ListC (не в конец)
    procedure AddMedium(ListN,ListC,ListK: PElem; r: TInfo);
    var Elem: PElem;
    begin
      new(Elem);
      Elem^.info:=r;
      Elem^.next:=ListC^.next; // после него то, что было после ListC
      ListC^.next:=Elem; // а он сам после ListC
    end;

procedure CreateList(var ListN, ListK: PElem; r: TInfo);
begin
  New(ListN);
  ListK:=ListN; // конец и начало совпадают
  ListN^.info:=r;
  ListN^.next:=nil;
end;
```

Проблема в том, что нули и отрицательные числа упорядочиваются в требуемом порядке, а положительные - в порядке, обратном требуемому. Например, при записи в список последовательности `1, 3, -4, 0, -5, 7` в списке будет последовательность `7, 3, 1, 0, -4, -5`. В чём ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
procedure AddR(var ListN, ListK: PElem; r: integer); // адреса начала и конца списка и R
var ListC: PElem;  // текущий элемент списка
begin
  if ListN = nil then
    CreateList(ListN, ListK, r) // если список пуст
  else if r < 0 then AddLast(ListN, ListK, r) // добавить в конец
  else begin // добавить после последнего положительного
    if ListN^.info <= 0 then  // Если первый элемент не положительный
      AddFirst(ListN, ListK, r) // добавить в начало
    else begin
      ListC := ListN; // с начала списка
      while (ListC^.next <> nil) and (ListC^.next^.info > 0) do
        ListC := ListC^.next;
      AddMedium(ListN, ListC, ListK, r); // добавить после текущего
      if ListC = ListK then  // Если добавляли в конец списка
        ListK := ListC^.next;  // то сместить конец списка
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Разворот происходит от вставки положительных в начало, т.е. до ранее найденных.

Вставляйте положительный элемент точно так же, как нулевой - ищете последний ненулевой, и вставляете после него.

```
procedure AddR(var ListN, ListK: PElem; r: integer); // адреса начала и конца списка и R
var ListC: PElem;  // текущий элемент списка
begin
   if ListN = nil then CreateList(ListN , ListK, r) // если список пуст
     else
         if r < 0 then AddLast(ListN, ListK, r) // добавить в конец
           else
             begin // найти после какого
               ListC:=ListN; // с начала списка
               while (ListC^.next <> nil) and (ListC^.next^.info > 0) do
               ListC := ListC^.next;
              AddMedium(ListN, ListC, ListK, r); // добавить после текущего
             end;
```

Однако с точки зрения производительности будет проще, если запоминать, куда вставили последний положительный - тогда и искать ничего не нужно, он и есть узел, после которого вставлять хоть ноль, хоть положительный.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы написать как это будет выглядеть? У меня уже голова не варит, 3 день реализовать не могу.